# GPU/Docker not working Ubuntu 20.04 in the WSL 2 of Windows

Tags: cuda, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm trying to follow [this](https://ubuntu.com/blog/getting-started-with-cuda-on-ubuntu-on-wsl-2) blog article to get CUDA working in a Ubuntu 20.04 kernel for non graphical machine learning running inside of WSL 2 under Windows 10 (build 20201.1000 with Nvidia driver 455.41) and am getting the error below for this command.

```
COMMAND:  docker run --gpus all nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody nbody -gpu -benchmark
RESPONSE: docker: Error response from daemon: could not select device driver "" with capabilities: [[gpu]].
```

The blog posting itself and other research suggests that docker may need to be restarted to address this problem but unfortunately the commands from the same blog posting about stopping and starting docker don't quite work (the stop does but not the start).

The start command is stated to be `sudo service docker stop` but I get a response of `docker: unrecognized service`.   Same thing if I try `sudo service docker start` which seems a more appropriate command to 'start' a service.

Note that I can get a list of services using `sudo service --status-all` but docker isn't listed.   It is however there somewhere as `docker --version` works.

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63012885/docker-unrecognized-service) other post suggested that the docker service may not be exposed or running.   Pretty sure it's running as the `wsl --shutdown Ubuntu` command from the blog article results in a Windows docker notification that docker stopped unexpectedly with a 'do you want to restart it?'

Saying yes to that also doesn't help so my suspicion is it's not being exposed but don't know how to check.

Comment: What are you ultimately trying to do? You can't run all apps in WSL. It's definitely not intended to support graphical applications: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/faq#can-i-run-all-linux-apps-in-wsl : **WSL is a tool aimed at enabling users who need them to run Bash and core Linux command-line tools on Windows.**

Comment: Have edited post to explain what I'm trying to do and some more details.

Comment: I suggest running Ubuntu in a VM.  WSL isn't intended to do what you want. Wrong tool for the job.

Comment: I was originally thinking I'd need to dual boot so I wouldn't have to deal with the hypervisor possibly not passing through the gpu properly and ran across this link which painted a fairly optimistic picture of using WSL 2 in this context https://towardsdatascience.com/dual-boot-is-dead-windows-and-linux-are-now-one-27555902a128   My windows build and the nvidia driver are both pre-release so maybe I just need to be patient until others iron out issues like I found which don't appear to affect everyone.

Comment: Fair enough, would you recommend a dual boot over a VM?  I normally don't worry about how the hypervisor exposes virtual hardware to guest OS' but I'm thinking that it might introduce a bottleneck or incompatibilities with gpu based ML if my Ubuntu doesn't have bare metal access.   I could probably muddle along doing my ML in Windows but I've been fighting getting certain cutting edge stuff to work locally (getting timeouts on Google Colab) just to find out some dependencies don't work on Windows.

Comment: If you want to run on the "bare metal", I'd definitely run dual boot instead of a VM

Comment: Ok, so I ended up with the dual boot bare metal which worked out very well for what I was trying to accomplish and what I envision doing going forward.   Think I may turn the situation around and just run Windows within a Ubuntu hosted VM going forward.   kvm & libvirt here I come...   Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

I had the exact same problem after following the exact same blog as you did. But I got to solve it as follows:

- Remove all docker and nvidia-docker related apps
- Follow the Docker installation steps from this site: [CUDA GPU accelerated support for WSL 2](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/wsl-user-guide/index.html#introduction). Ignore the Docker Desktop warning that will prompt when running `curl https://get.docker.com | sh`.

You will most likely run into this error `docker: Error response from daemon: cgroups: cannot find cgroup mount destination: unknown. ERRO[0026] error waiting for container: context canceled` when running `docker run --gpus all nvcr.io/nvidia/k8s/cuda-sample:nbody nbody -gpu -benchmark`. If that is the case, run the following commands ([more info here](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/docker-error-response-from-daemon-could-not-select-device-driver-with-capabilities-gpu/128913/4)):

- `sudo mkdir /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd`
- `sudo mount -t cgroup -o none,name=systemd cgroup /sys/fs/cgroup/systemd`

Once you have run those steps it should work. Note that as for today, 05/10/2020, there seems to be an error in the current Windows Insider Preview (20226.1000) that prevents any interaction with CUDA. Check the following link for more info: ([CUDA error: all CUDA-capable devices are busy or unavailable](https://forums.developer.nvidia.com/t/cuda-error-all-cuda-capable-devices-are-busy-or-unavailable/156084)).

Most likely you will have to wait until another Windows Update is launched to solve the last one.

Hope it helps!

EDIT: Windows Insider Preview version 20236 works just fine! You might want to check that.